# Pandas: matching a string in series with string from another series

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, match

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Full                          Partial
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ    FGHIJKL
ANLHDFKNADHFBAKHFGBAKJFB      FKNADH
JABFKADFNADKHFBADHBFJDHFBADF  ABFKA
```

What I want to do is to put everything from `Full` that does NOT match `Partial` in lowercase, yielding the following:

```
Coverage
abcdef_GHIJKL_mnopqrstuvwxyz
anlhd_FKNADH_fbakhfgbakjfb
j_ABFKA_dfnadkhfbadhbfjdhfbadf
```

How would I do this? I looked around and it seems that `series.str.extract()` could be a solution, but I'm not certain as when I try to do this:

```
df['Full'].str.extract(data['Partial'])
```

... it only says that Series can't be hashable. I assume that `extract` only takes a single argument, rather than a Series? Is there any way to bypass this? Is `extract` even the correct way to achieve what I'm looking for, or is there another way? I'm thinking I could perhaps find som way to extract the string indexes and do the following pseudocode:

```
df['Coverage'] = data['Full'][:start].lower() + '_' + data['Partial'] + \
     '_' + data['Full'][End:].lower()
```

... where `Start` and `End` is the indexes for where `data['Partial']` starts and ends, respectively. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant perhaps, but here is one solution:

For df:

```
                           Full  Partial
0    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ  FGHIJKL
1      ANLHDFKNADHFBAKHFGBAKJFB   FKNADH
2  JABFKADFNADKHFBADHBFJDHFBADF    ABFKA
```

This:

```
df.apply(lambda r: r.Full.lower().replace(r.Partial.lower(), '_' + r.Partial + '_'), axis=1)
```

Returns:

```
0      abcde_FGHIJKL_mnopqrstuvwxyz
1        anlhd_FKNADH_fbakhfgbakjfb
2    j_ABFKA_dfnadkhfbadhbfjdhfbadf
```

For each row, you convert the full string to lowercase, and replace the 'partial string to lower' with the original partial string with two underscores added on both sides.

Comment: Awesome, that's EXACTLY what I wanted! In what way is it not elegant, and what does the `r` in the lambda function stand for? (I don't know much about lambda, I'm afraid)